# Telerik MVC Grid JavaScript is loaded when not specified

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have the following in web layout (master page):

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
   .DefaultGroup(group => group
      .DefaultPath("~/Assets/telerikaspnetmvc/2011.2.712/Scripts/")
      .Add("telerik.common.min.js")
      .Add("telerik.treeview.min.js")
      .Compress(true))
   .jQuery(false)
)
```

On one of my views I created a grid.  But I did not specify in the ScriptRegistrar that it must use telerik.grid.min.js.  After the page has loaded in IE I viewed the source and it showed:

Why would this be?  Does it load the necessary scripts as needed?

Also, I'm confused at to what JavaScripts are needed by the grids.  There are a couple, namely: telerik.grid.editing.min.js, telerik.grid.filtering.min.js, telerik.grid.grouping.min.js, etc, etc.  When are these to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-required-javascript-files.html).